# Java swing: Extended jpanel class will not brighten upon repainting.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouseevent

I have done much more complicated problems with no issues for my course, but this is giving me fits! My problem is simple, I cannot brighten or change the color of my jpanels. I feel I a missing something crucial in how my extended jpanel class interacts with my overridden paint component as well as my other classes. The mission is simple, when one jpanel is clicked it's color should brighten, while the other two colors dim.

Run down: I extended Jframe and added 3 panels to it. I have added a mouse listener to each. When each is pressed the mouse listener does work "print statements confirmed". However it does not change the objects color. I thought that by including my mouse adapter in my TrafficLight class I would be able to change the color and call repaint. I have played with in all the ways I can think, is my organization wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class TrafficLight3 extends JFrame {

//class variables
public JPanel red;
public JPanel yellow;
public JPanel green;
public Color r;
public Color y;
public Color gr;

public static void main ( String [] args ) {
    TrafficLight3 tl = new TrafficLight3 ( );
}

// Constructor 
public TrafficLight3( ) {

    setTitle( "Traffic Light" );
    setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 3, 1 ) );
    setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    r = Color.RED;
    red = new StopLightPanel( 100, r );
    red.setPreferredSize( new Dimension ( 120, 120 ) ); 
    red.addMouseListener ( new MouseClicked( ) );
    add( red );

    y = Color.YELLOW;
    yellow = new StopLightPanel( 100, y );
    yellow.setPreferredSize( new Dimension ( 120, 120 ) );
    yellow.addMouseListener ( new MouseClicked( ) );
    add( yellow );        

    gr = Color.GREEN;
    green = new StopLightPanel( 100, gr );
    green.addMouseListener ( new MouseClicked( ) );
    green.setPreferredSize( new Dimension ( 120, 120 ) ); 
    add ( green );        

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible( true );
  }
  class MouseClicked extends MouseAdapter {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked ( MouseEvent me ) {
         if (me.getSource().equals( red ) ) {
             r = r.brighter();
             y = y.darker();
             gr = gr.darker();
             repaint();
      }
      if (me.getSource().equals( yellow )) {
             r = r.darker();
             y = y.brighter();
             gr = gr.darker();
             repaint();
      }
      if (me.getSource().equals( red )) {
             r = r.darker();
             y = y.darker();
             gr = gr.brighter();
             repaint();
      }
  }
 }

class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {

    private int diameter;
    public Color color;

    public StopLightPanel ( int d, Color c) {

        diameter = d;
        color = c;
    }

    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {

        super.paintComponent( g );
        g.setColor ( color );
        g.fillOval ( 10, 10, diameter, diameter );
   }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're changing a variable's value in one location, and expecting a completely different variable, the one owned by the JPanel, to change in concert, but that's not how variables work.

Instead, I would give my stop light panel a method, say `public void setLightOn(boolean lightOn)` and would call this method in my MouseListener. The method would change the color of the JPanel and repaint it.

For example:

```
class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {

  private int diameter;
  private Color onColor;
  private Color offColor;
  private boolean lightOn;

  public boolean isLightOn() {
     return lightOn;
  }

  public void setLightOn(boolean lightOn) {
     this.lightOn = lightOn;
     repaint();
  }

  public StopLightPanel(int d, Color c) {

     diameter = d;
     onColor = c.brighter();
     offColor = c.darker().darker();
     lightOn = false;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

     super.paintComponent(g);
     Color color = lightOn ? onColor : offColor;
     g.setColor(color);
     g.fillOval(10, 10, diameter, diameter);
  }
}
```

For example,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TrafficLight3 extends JFrame {
   private static final int DIAMETER = 100;
   private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green };
   private StopLightPanel[] lightPanels = new StopLightPanel[COLORS.length];

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new TrafficLight3();
         }
      });
   }

   public TrafficLight3() {
      setTitle("Traffic Light");
      setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

      MouseAdapter mouseClicked = new MouseClicked();
      for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
         lightPanels[i] = new StopLightPanel(DIAMETER, COLORS[i]);
         lightPanels[i].addMouseListener(mouseClicked);
         add(lightPanels[i]);
      }
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   class MouseClicked extends MouseAdapter {
      // better overriding mousePressed not mouseClicked
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
         // set all lights dark
         for (StopLightPanel lightPanel : lightPanels) {
            lightPanel.setLightOn(false);
         }

         // turn only selected light on.
         ((StopLightPanel) me.getSource()).setLightOn(true);
      }
   }

   class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {
      // avoid "magic" numbers
      private static final int GAP = 10;
      private int diameter;
      private Color onColor;
      private Color offColor;
      private boolean lightOn;

      public boolean isLightOn() {
         return lightOn;
      }

      public void setLightOn(boolean lightOn) {
         this.lightOn = lightOn;
         repaint();
      }

      public StopLightPanel(int diameter, Color color) {
         this.diameter = diameter;
         this.onColor = color.brighter();
         this.offColor = color.darker().darker();
         this.lightOn = false;
      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         int prefW = diameter + 2 * GAP;
         int prefH = prefW;
         return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         // smooth out the edge of our circle
         g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         Color color = lightOn ? onColor : offColor;
         g2.setColor(color);
         g2.fillOval(GAP, GAP, diameter, diameter);
      }
   }
}
```

Somewhat MCV-ified. Missing interfaces though

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TrafficLight3  {

   private static final int DIAMETER = 100;

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      StopLightModel model = new StopLightModel();
      StopLightView view = new StopLightView(DIAMETER);
      new StopLightControl(view, model);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Light");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

enum MyColor {
   RED(Color.red, "Red"),
   YELLOW(Color.yellow, "Yellow"),
   GREEN(Color.green, "Green");

   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   private MyColor(Color color, String name) {
      this.color = color;
      this.name = name;
   }
   private Color color;
   private String name;
}

class StopLightModel {
   public static final String SELECTED_COLOR = "selected color";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private MyColor selectedColor = null;

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public MyColor getSelectedColor() {
      return selectedColor;
   }

   public void setSelectedColor(MyColor selectedColor) {
      MyColor oldValue = this.selectedColor;
      MyColor newValue = selectedColor;
      this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(SELECTED_COLOR, oldValue, newValue);
   }

}

class StopLightControl {
   private StopLightView view;
   private StopLightModel model;

   public StopLightControl(final StopLightView view, final StopLightModel model) {
      this.view = view;
      this.model = model;
      view.setStopLightControl(this);
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new ModelListener());
   }

   public void setSelectedColor(MyColor myColor) {
      model.setSelectedColor(myColor);
   }

   private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (StopLightModel.SELECTED_COLOR.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            MyColor myColor = model.getSelectedColor();
            view.setSelectedColor(myColor);
         }
      }
   }

}

class StopLightView {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
   private StopLightControl control;
   private Map<MyColor, StopLightPanel> colorPanelMap = new EnumMap<>(MyColor.class);

   public StopLightView(int diameter) {
      MouseAdapter mouseClicked = new MouseClicked();
      for (MyColor myColor : MyColor.values()) {
         StopLightPanel lightPanel = new StopLightPanel(diameter, myColor);
         lightPanel.addMouseListener(mouseClicked);
         mainPanel.add(lightPanel);
         colorPanelMap.put(myColor, lightPanel);
      }
   }

   public void setSelectedColor(MyColor myColor) {
      for (MyColor color : MyColor.values()) {
         colorPanelMap.get(color).setLightOn(color == myColor);
      }
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public void setStopLightControl(StopLightControl control) {
      this.control = control;
   }

   private class MouseClicked extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         if (control == null) {
            return;
         }

         StopLightPanel panel = (StopLightPanel) mEvt.getSource();
         control.setSelectedColor(panel.getMyColor());
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class StopLightPanel extends JPanel {
   // avoid "magic" numbers
   private static final int GAP = 10;
   private int diameter;
   private MyColor myColor;
   private Color onColor;
   private Color offColor;
   private boolean lightOn;

   public boolean isLightOn() {
      return lightOn;
   }

   public void setLightOn(boolean lightOn) {
      this.lightOn = lightOn;
      repaint();
   }

   public StopLightPanel(int diameter, MyColor myColor) {
      this.diameter = diameter;
      this.myColor = myColor;
      this.onColor = myColor.getColor().brighter();
      this.offColor = myColor.getColor().darker().darker();
      this.lightOn = false;
   }

   public MyColor getMyColor() {
      return myColor;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      int prefW = diameter + 2 * GAP;
      int prefH = prefW;
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // smooth out the edge of our circle
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Color color = lightOn ? onColor : offColor;
      g2.setColor(color);
      g2.fillOval(GAP, GAP, diameter, diameter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful. I thought that mouseListener would have access to my color variables and thus be able to change them and calling repaint would display the new tone.

Answer (score 4):

There is no relationship between the color you are changing in the `actionListener` and the color the panel is using to paint itself.

Taking a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#darker%28%29) you would note that

> darker/brighter
>
> **Returns:**
>  Creates a new `Color` that is a darker/brighter version
>   of this `Color`.

`darker`/`brighter` doesn't change the `Color` object itself, but creates a new `Color` object which is `darker`/`brighter` than the color you are using

What you should probably do is set the color you want to each panel when the `actionListener` triggered.

Better yet, you should be using some kind of model, changing the model would notify each instance of the panel and it would then respond by updating itself...

Comment: I did take time to read the java doc and that was my interpenetration of it.  I thought that by calling repaint it would draw the objects again and having changed my public variable to a new color it would be with that color variable. As hovercraft said below I didn't really change the color at all. This helped thank you.

Comment: @user2557015 Sorry for my assumption